# Does C++ guarantee shortcutting for compile time constants?

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I have a compile-time condition, using `std::conditional<cond, TypeA, TypeB>`.  In my case, the condition is a disjunction, along the lines of `SimpleCondition<T>::value || ComplexCondition<T>::value`.  In my case T is a list of length n, and I can show that `SimpleCondition<T>::value` can be processed in O(1) time, while `ComplexCondition<T>::Value` requires O(n) time.  I would like to rely on shortcutting to ensure I don't compute the O(n) side every single time... assuming I can.

If these were runtime functions instead of compile time constants, it would be easy to show that `simpleCondition(t) || complexCondition(t)` will shortcut.  Is shortcutting guaranteed for compile time constants too?

As a more extreme case, consider the case where SimpleCondition is being used to work around the halting problem.  Perhaps `ComplexCondition<T>::value` can be proven to terminate for many values, but that proof is unavailable for cases where `SimpleCondition<T>::value` is true.  In such a circumstance, this question of shortcutting would be the difference between a program that provably compiles and one that does not.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. If `SimpleCondition<T>::value` evaluates to true at complile time then the `if` condition and the `else` branch are thrown away.

Comment: If you are asking whether `ComplexCondition<T>::value` is instantiated - yes. It has to be, because failure to instantiate is itself a signal that may affect compilation when using SFINAE techniques.

Comment: *"I would like to rely on shortcutting to ensure I don't compute the O(n) side every single time"* -- You're talking about a compile-time condition, so there is only one time, right?

Comment: @JaMiT One time, per translation unit, at compile time.  As long as n is small, its a minor concern. But if n is large (or the function is undecidable), that's a bigger issue

Comment: I have seen compilers taken to their knees by an ill-planned O(n^3) algorithm written into templates.

Comment: @CortAmmon *"But if n is large (or the function is undecidable), that's a bigger issue"* -- I wasn't questioning the issue, but the phrasing of "every single time". That's more a description of a runtime concern, not the one-time (per translation unit) when compiling. For compile-time, *"to ensure I don't compute the O(n) side when not necessary"* seems more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When evaluating `SimpleCondition<T>::value || ComplexCondition<T>::value` the compiler looks up and instantiates `SimpleCondition<T>` and `ComplexCondition<T>` and then looks up the `value` member. The instantiation is what actually does any compile time evaluation, so while the eventual (assuming they both are `true`) `true || true` would "short circuit", no extra work would need to be done at that point.

The solution is to use [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction).

`std::disjunction_v<SimpleCondition<T>, ComplexCondition<T>>` gives essentially the same result, but will not instantiate `ComplexCondition<T>` if `SimpleCondition<T>::value` is `true`. This means if `ComplexCondition<T>` would have an error (e.g., an infinite recursion), or it would just take a lot of compile time resources to compute, they just won't happen.

(And `std::conjunction_v` for the `&&` case)

Comment: I'd seen the verbage on disjunction for that, but it didn't occur to me at the time just why they put those words in.   Thank you!